# Unable to connect react-native debugger in Ubuntu(22.04)

Tags: react-native, react-devtools, react-native-debugger

I am trying to install react native debugger(version 0.12.1) in ubuntu. The error message was as displayed in this screenshot on first launch.[image]

However, even after installing `react-devtools ^4.22.0` globally , it continues to display the same error message. I also looked into this [discussion](https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/4bc90775530873fdf8e7ade4a039e579) but it was not helpful.I am using npm as a package manager tool..

Any kind of help will be appreciable !!

**Update-1 :** I was able to successfully connect to the debugger ui. But i was unable to access element inspector and redux state.